# how can i push an array of strings into a model?

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript

I have an array of strings, I really want to push them into the model but I dont know how to achieve this. this is my function:

```
cds = [];    `

addBand(name, genre) {
          console.log(name,genre);
          //const nummer = new Nummer();
          const band = new Band({ 'name': name,
             'genre': genre   'cd': [
               'name' : this.cds.push(num)
            ]
          console.log('band', band);
          this.bandsService.addBand(band);
      }
```

I dont know how to push it into my model because it is a array, and I have to put 'name' in front of every object in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you have a cd-object, that contains a name and the cd's length.
Define it like this.

```
export class CD {
   constructor(
      public name: string,
      public length: number
   ) {}
}
```

Next you have an object Band that takes name, genre and the list of cds.
Here it is.

```
export class Band {
   constructor(
      public name: string,
      public genre: string,
      public cds: Array<CD>
   ) {}
}
```

To use them together you could act like this.

Create your CD-collection

```
private cds: Array<CD> = [];

private summarizeCds(): void {
  let cd = new CD('the dark side', 120);
  this.cds.push(cd);

  cd = new CD('winter in paradise', 133);
  this.cds.push(cd);

  cd = new CD('hell raises', 666);
  this.cds.push(cd);

  [...]
}
```

And then complete your Band-object with this:

```
private addBand(name: string, genre: string, cds: Array<CD>) {
      console.log(name,genre);

      const band = new Band(
         name,
         genre,
         cds
      );

      console.log('band', band);
      this.bandsService.addBand(band);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment, I editted my post to clearify things

Comment: Well, actually this was no comment but intended to be a solution to your question. But anyway, I re-edited my post. Does this fit your needs now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your intent but this is what I came up with:

```
cds = [];

addBand(name, genre) {
  console.log(name, genre);
  //const nummer = new Nummer();
  const band = new Band({
    'name': name,
    'genre': genre,
    'cd': [
      'name': name
    ]
  });
  this.cds.push(band)
  console.log('band', band);
  this.bandsService.addBand(band);
}
```

Kindly let me know if this is not what you intended.

Comment: Hey!

Thank you, but no this is not what i intended, I have an array called CDS with strings in it. I also have a Model called Cd, this model contains a name, and a length of the cd. the Cd Model, is an array inside the bandmodel, and When I enter a band, I also want to add a few cd's this band made. I am already able to enter the band like this:

Comment: const band = new Band({ 'name': name,
         'genre': genre  
        ]
      console.log('band', band);
      this.bandsService.addBand(band);

Comment: But I dont know how to push my cds array to this band, so it will fit, because this cds array only contains names, and these are just strings

Comment: Could you reproduce this on codesandbox.io, I would love to help

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me, I am sorry about being so unclear so let me clearify this.
I have an array called CDS with strings in it(those strings are cd names). I also have a Model called Cd, this model contains a name, and a length of the cd. the Cd Model, is an array inside the bandmodel, and When I enter a band, I also want to add a few cd's this band made. I am already able to enter the band like this

```
const band = new Band({ 'name': name, 'genre': genre ] 
console.log('band', band); 
this.bandsService.addBand(band);
```

But I dont know how to read the cds array and fit it in the Cd model and push it to the band.